# ThreeJS Connecting to various coordinates

Tags: three.js

Hi I have an external file that contains many xyz coordinate points. In my threeJS file, I use these points as vertices and push to a geometry and create a point cloud. However, the result looks like many points scattering around. Do you how I can connect these points so that they are more connected than they are now? Here is my code.

```js
var dataxyz = xyz; 
//xyz is a variable that is an array containing all xyz  coordinates.
var particleCount=Object.keys(dataxyz).length;
var coOef =100;
for (var i=0;i<particleCount;i++) {

        var coOrd=dataxyz[i];
        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        vertex.x = coOrd[0] * coOef;
        vertex.y = coOrd[2] * coOef-(coOef*2.5);
        vertex.z = coOrd[1] * coOef;

    }
var Size = 0.1;
this.materials= new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({size: Size});
this.particles = new THREE.PointCloud(this.geometry, this.materials);
this.scene.add(this.particles);
```

Comment: I cannot run the code snippet. What do you mean with "more connected"?

Comment: Hi Juagicre, the xyz is a variable in a .js format outside.. so in my html i would have <script type="text/javascript" src="mydata.js"></script>.. inside mydata.js, there is a variable  called "xyz" which is like xyz=[{1,2,3},{4,5,6)....] all the xyz coordinates... so when i used the code above, it will show a pic full of individual dots... i just wonder how i could make them look like a more mesh.

Comment: I understand. You can always triangulate over all your coordinates, even is a bit strange to do so in a "cloud of particles" context.